# Here maps: Is it possible to use javascript api with offline support from iOS SDK(premium)?

Tags: here-api

I am developing an cordova app which consumes google js api for mapping currently. Now my client wants to use offline maps using Here Maps. Is it possible to use combined version of js api for mapping, routing etc and offline support from SDK?

Comment: This question is **way** to broad. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @pperry i didn't ask for writing code brother (can do it myself). I just wanted suggestions, which i got and helped me to get my work done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. I was missing NMABundle.bundle file in my project. Just added and everything started working. :) Thanks @david-leong

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is possible to build a cordova plugin to bridge between the Cordova JS interface and the iOS ObjectiveC world. Please see the cordova plugin documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html).

The interesting part is how to add the NMAMapView into the Cordova webview. you will need to write a binding plugin similar to [this](https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit).

Comment: i am able bridge cordova and native objc. But i am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line 

NMAMapView *mapView = [[NMAMapView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

If i use apple map kit. It works just fine.

Comment: Did you setup permission strings and the other init logic required prior to alloc init?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have setup api keys/license keys. No idea about other init logic prior to alloc init (there is nothing in Here Maps SDK documentation about that)

I am a javascript developer. Don't know much about Obj C.

Comment: i can share xcode project if you want. @david-leong

Comment: @RameezRaja That would be highly appreciated. Could you please upload your xcode project to github?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The JS API is online only...

Comment: I believe he means to build a cordova iOS app, which can have native code plugins.